# PHP composer install Problems

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a big problem with php composer, I run this command

```
php composer.phar install
```

but it show me this error

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:
  PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/lcp-api/app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/lcp-api/app/console on line 10
  PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/lcp-api/app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/
  lcp-api/app/console on line 10
  .
```

I check the file composer.json and it seems that everything is okay

```
"post-install-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
  },
```

Do you have any idea why I get this error?

Cordially

Comment: Does the file `/var/www/lcp-api/app/bootstrap.php.cache` exist?

Comment: No, that's the problem I do not have this file. I checked in other post and they say that Symphony generate it

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `bootstrap.php.cache` file is missing. This can happen sometimes with Symfony.

The file *should* be regenerated if you run `composer update` instead of `install`. If that doesn't work, you can generate it manually by running this command from the root of your project:

```
php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

If that also doesn't work, you can try to force your environment to production mode by running composer like this:

```
SYMFONY_ENV=prod composer install
```

Keep in mind that if you do that on your development environment, debug-mode will be disabled. This should generate a bootstrap.php.cache file, so you should then be able to re-run composer in dev mode again.

Comment: When I run the second command I get this "v2.1.62" do you know what it means?

Comment: That's odd, `build_bootstrap` should not give any output if all went well. It's not the Symfony or Sensio version number, because their 2.1.x versions don't go up to 62. Are you using a reasonably recent version of Symfony? We're up to version 3.3.9 (or 2.8.27 if you're stuck on 2). I can't replicate that behavior on either version.